# literal string expected error

Tags: oop, ada, gnat, gnat-gps

Please have a look at the following code

```
with text_io;
use text_io;

procedure hello is

begin
put_line("hello");
new_line(3);
end hello;
```

When I click "build all" in GPS IDE, I get this error

```
gnatmake -d -PC:\Users\yohan\firstprogram.gpr
firstprogram.gpr:1:06: literal string expected
firstprogram.gpr:2:01: "end" expected
gnatmake: "C:\Users\yohan\firstprogram.gpr" processing failed

[2013-04-03 13:29:58] process exited with status 4 (elapsed time: 00.47s)
```

I am very new to Ada, as you can see, this is my first program. Please help.

Comment: with Ada.text_io; use Ada.text_io;  -- the I/O packages are children of the Ada package. and this should be saved as .adb (Ada program Body) not .gpr which is a replacement for a Makefile.

Comment: Actually, Brian, `with Text_IO;` is legal Ada; it's an [obsolescent renaming](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-J-1.html#p6) of `Ada.Text_IO`.

Comment: @Yohan: Your program runs correctly from the command line using `gnatmake hello` and `./hello`.

Comment: okay I stand corrected on Text_IO. Sounds like some confusion between source and project files then.

Comment: @trashgod: Thanks for the reply, but then why not using GSP?

Comment: Can anyone assist me on making a Ada project in GSP IDE? What I have is "GNAT GPL 2012"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, `gnatmake` will happily compile a file which contains Ada code but has the extension `.gpr`. GPS knows "better" than that, and insists on treating `myfirstprogram.gpr` as a GNAT Project file, which of course it isn't.

You'll find life with GNAT *much* easier if you stick with its file naming conventions: `.ads` for a spec, `.adb` for a body, and the file name needs to be the unit name in lower case. In your case, the file should have been called `hello.adb`.

The simplest approach to creating a GNAT project file in GPS is to go to the *Project* menu and select *New*. The only places where you must enter data are on the "Naming the project" page (you might choose `firstproject`!) and the "Main files" page, where you'd click on the blue + to add `hello.adb`; you can *Forward* through the others.

After adding the main file, you can click *Apply* to install the new project file; now you can *Build all* and *Run*.

You may find the GPS tutorial helpful (*Help* menu, *GPS* ...)